Wix Velo: Get FormFields to Submit with checkoutBooking?
One of the arguments that needs to be submitted when using checkoutBooking is the FormFields collection object that is based on the Custom Booking Form for the service I want to book. I am gathering the client data for the checkoutBooking from a custom Sign Up form I created myself. When looking at examples, I see that the FormField object should have a key-value pair where the key is the ‘_id’ for each of the fields that the Custom Booking Form uses. I do not know how to obtain these ‘_id’ numbers. In this case, how can I successfully instantiate a FormFields object with the correct information for the service I am booking?

There is an area of the Wix dashboard called the CMS.  CMS stands for Content Management System and contains the definitions of the data objects in the site.  This includes the 'Wix App Collections'.  Under this category, there are the subcategories of 'Schedule', 'Services', and 'Staff'.  If you go into the 'Services' subcategory, you will see a table that represents all of the Services objects that have been defined for the site.  One of the last columns in this table is the 'Form Fields' column.  That column defines all of the Form Fields in the bookingform for that Service.  It contains the definition for each Form Field, including the unique ID for each field.
For example:
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000",
      "label": "Email",
      "constraints": {
        "required": true
      },
      "link": null,
      "type": "email"
    },
    {
      "_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000",
      "label": "Phone Number",
      "constraints": {
        "required": false
      },
      "link": null,
      "type": "tel"
    },
    {
      "_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000",
      "label": "Name",
      "constraints": {
        "required": true
      },
      "link": null,
      "type": "text"
    },
    {
      "_id": "ea32d7b8-8234-4911-939d-b0e41f1cf6",
      "label": "Referral",
      "constraints": {
        "required": false
      },
      "link": null,
      "type": "text"
    }
  ]
}

